# Как сделать проверку ссылки в тексте?

Tags: php, проверка

Ну например такая проверка:
Если в тексте найдётся ссылка с началом http:// или https:// то 
 ничего не произойдёт
Или если в тексте найдётся ссылка без http:// или https:// то
К ссылке добавится http://

Для меня это сложный вопрос, помогите пожалуйста. 
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Как решать, что ссылка, а что нет? click.it это ссылка или нет? А follow.me? А windows.sucks?

Answer (score 3):

Самый легкий вариант добавить все имеющиеся доменные зоны в массив и при наличии такового считать ссылкой. Тем самым образуется устойчивая фильтрация доменных имен. В вашем вопросе присутствовало добавление http и https которое реализовать можно регулярным выражением добавленным ранее, опорой поиска которого будет служить тот же массив с доменными зонами, а также не считать доменными именами даже те, в которых будет присутствовать домен с http без существующей зоны (по желанию). Тем самым к доменам вида: lol.kek не будет применяться добавление конструкции. Логично и практично

Answer (score 2):

Замените регуляркой все урлы без префикса на урлы с префиксом. Только вам придётся определить для себя, что у вас является урлом без префикса. Ниже простой пример для частного случая. Усложняйте на своё усмотрение.

```
$str = "foo site1.ru bar http://site2.ru baz";
$str = preg_replace('#\b(?<!http://)([a-z\d]+\.[a-z]{2,3})\b#i', 'http://\1', $str);
var_dump($str);
```

Выводит:

```
string(43) "foo http://site1.ru bar http://site2.ru baz"
```

Регулярка читается так:

- `#\b .. \b#i`  - между двумя границами слова и не учитывая регистр букв
- `([a-z\d]+\.[a-z]{2,3})` - найти такие похожие на урлы строки
- `(?<!http://)` - слева у которых нет префикса `http://`
- и заменить их на то что нашли, но уже с префиксом слева - `http://\1`

Comment: `http://www.mail.ru -> http://www.http://mail.ru` (http://www.http://mail.ru -- парсер so тоже спотыкнулся)

Comment: Не так все просто. Уже давным-давно есть TLD длиной более трех символов, не говоря уже о таких популярных зонах, как .рф, .қаз и, допустим, .ไทย

Comment: замечания дельные, и я конечно в курсе, но мы с вами не знаем чего точно хочет автор вопроса; поэтому я и уточнил, что пример для частного синтетического случая, а не общего. так-то ещё можно про гет-аргументы справа от хоста вспомнить

Answer (score 1):

1) надо найти .ru , .com , .kz и тому подобное
2) надо этот фрагмент записать в переменную до пробела например: (ыва mail.ru -> mail.ru) 
3) вставить http:// с помощью конкатенаций строк.
4) найти и заменить  в тексте mail.ru  и заменить на http://mail.ru